# Can't access MAAS Web UI after installing

Tags: maas

I installed [MAAS](https://maas.io/) on Bionic by following [the steps on their site](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/provisioning). I was able to `sudo maas init` and set up a user, but I can't access the web UI either from another computer or locally using `curl http://localhost:5240/MAAS/`. All the documentation for this I found was very old, and described steps that don't seem to work on Bionic.

Side question: is MAAS worth installing in 2018 or should I look into alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else running into this problem:

Installing through `apt` doesn't seem to work on Bionic. Instead, try:

```
sudo snap install maas --devmode
```

After doing this and running `sudo maas init`, I was able to access the web UI.